# wix getting user input

Tags: wix, user-input

Dialog.wxs

```
<UI>
<Dialog Id="UserRegistrationDlg" ... >
<Control Id="NameEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="85" Width="220" Height="18" Property="NameValue" Text="{80}" />
</Dialog>
<UI>
```

In Product.wxs I created a property

```
<Property Id="NameValueProperty" Value="NameValue" />
```

Then, as I understood, I have to use [NameValueProperty] for getting value but id doesn't work ... What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally want to use a Secure Custom Property  in this situation.  This is a property that is both [Public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (i.e. CAPS ) and marked as [Secure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)   A value is only required if you want there to be a default value.

```
<Property Id="MYPROPERTY" Secure="yes" />
```

Comment: This is only necessary if you need the value to pass from the UI to the InstallExecuteSequence. Depends very much on how the Property is being used.

Comment: Hence why I said 'generally'.  I would think that generally you are going to do something to the machine with the data collected and hence it most likely will need to be a secure custom property.

Answer (score 5):

A verbose log file should show you the changes to the properties. Very useful when tracking down these sort of things. In this case, your example code is actually setting a Property called `NameValue` to the value in the edit box. If you want to default the value in the edit box then you would do something like:

```
<Property Id="NameValue" Value="Show this in the edit box" />
```

And to reference the value you'd use `[NameValue]`.  Alternatively, you could change your code to be:

```
<UI>
  <Dialog Id="UserRegistrationDlg" ... >
    <Control Id="NameEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="85" Width="220"
             Height="18" Property="NameValueProperty" Text="{80}" />
  <Dialog>
<UI>
```

Comment: how did you get this to work? I used this code but nothing shows up in the UI

Comment: use `Property="MY_TEXT"` in the control and define a Property in the Product.exs file with the same id: `<Property Id="MY_TEXT Value="My awesome text"/>`.